# How to remove shower handle?

Tags: plumbing, shower, demolition

I have this handle attached to the shower wall (as a kit):

[image]

[image]

I frankly cannot figure out how to remove the while plastic piece and the metal piece outside of it in order to pull the large round cover.

Here is what in the back of the shower wall:

[image]

Or should I use a saw and cut right at that plastic piece? I am not sure if there is metal in the middle. My saw is not good enough.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is the same shower, but it resembles yours: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkPcCmYkG4Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a screw inside right in the middle. It is hard to see but once removed, the handle is out.